# How to check if a dynamic background image is too big to fit in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[<kbd>Sample code</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/8979/)

I have an element (most likely a `div`) that might be affeccted by the window size (or not). The user can pick any image as the `div`'s `background-image` and I need to check if that image is too big and if it is I need to toggle on `background-size: contain`. I am not sure how to grab the size of the background image `onload` and how to compare that with the `div`. I think this requires a custom directive but I did not find any similar example.

On a sidenote, why does the image in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/8979/) remain the same when the url is changed?

Comment: You can load the image to a temporary img tag and check the height and width of the image. But the issue is that you need some solid unit to compare against. Since you have the container dimensions in percentage you would need to get their rendered dimensions to decide if it exceeds or not.

Comment: @PSL Is there any way to get the height and width of the div? How do I address the div that owns the background-image? I basically need the `div` to remember the loaded `background-image`'s width and height, and check against them every time the window changes.